# How can I return data in method from Retrofit i am confused?

Tags: retrofit2

I am confused please can you help me? I read similar questions but its is not clear for me, thanks in advance for your patient and attention.

I want to return to onCreate data which retrieved from API call using Retrofit. Here is my function where i call Retrofit.

private void loadTimeZoneAPI(double latitude, double longitude, long timestamp, String apiKeyTz) {

```
    String lat = Double.toString(latitude);
    String lon = Double.toString(longitude);
    String time = Long.toString(timestamp);

    serviceTZ.getDataTZ(lat+","+lon, time, apiKeyTz).enqueue(new Callback<TimeZoneGoogle>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TimeZoneGoogle> call, Response<TimeZoneGoogle> response) {
            TimeZoneGoogle result = response.body();
            timeZone = result.getTimeZoneId();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TimeZoneGoogle> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

How i will return timeZone value to onCreate where i will use for calculation.

Comment: share your class where you want to return data and class in which you are having data from server

Comment: @vikaskumar  Here is my link for my class https://gist.github.com/ArnalShoorukov/8776041dc998bafc1d9c8370f6a3760c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a callback listener for your data in MainActivity or any activity you have used for view.
for example:make interface like this

```
interface RetrofitListener{
        onDataLoad(TimeZoneGoogle timeZoneGoogle);
    }
```

then give a reference in Activity from which you are calling Retrofit class

```
public class ActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityTest.RetrofitListener {

    RetrofitCall retrofitListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        retrofitListener = new RetrofitCall(this);
    }
}
```

and here in RetrofitCall class

```
 private class RetrofitCall {
        private RetrofitListener retrofitListener;

        public RetrofitCall(RetrofitListener retrofitListener) {
            this.retrofitListener = retrofitListener;
        }
 void getData(){
    getDataTZ(lat+","+lon, time, apiKeyTz).enqueue(new Callback<TimeZoneGoogle>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TimeZoneGoogle> call, Response<TimeZoneGoogle> response) {
                TimeZoneGoogle result = response.body();
                timeZone = result.getTimeZoneId();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TimeZoneGoogle> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
}
```